# How to switch the user and to pass the password along in Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins

How to switch the user and to pass the password along in Groovy script? As I am working in Jenkins Pipeline plugin, wanted to execute some commands with root privilege, but default user is jenkins.

Code is:

```
node {
     sh "whoami"   
     }
```

Output is:

```
[test_cdpipeline] Running shell script
+ whoami
jenkins
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do with &&.like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                script{
                    sh 'export KUBECONFIG=/home/k8stest/.kube/config && kubectl get nodes'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this switch users? Your answer explains how to provide `kubectl` with the configuration it needs, it doesn’t explain how to run commands as root...